# Why is this normal bundle a subset of the tangent bundle?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M \subset V$ be a submanifold, $\delta M = \delta V = \emptyset$. Let $v = (p,E,M)$ be the normal bundle of $M$ in $V$. Then:

Then we have:

$v \subset T_M V \subset T_M \mathbb{R}^n = M \times \mathbb{R}^n$

I'm a little bit confused on why the normal bundle of $M$ in $V$ is containd in $T_M V$. A part of me wants to think they are disjoint, because one is the tangent bundle and the other is the normal bundle... W hat am I not understanding here? Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining the normal bundle? If $M\subseteq V=\mathbb R^n$ is an embedded $m$- dimensional submanifold, which you can always do, by Whitney Embedding theorem, then if $x\in M,\ T_xM$ is identified with an $m$-dimensional subspace of $T_xR^n$, so $T_xR^n$ splits into a direct sum of $T_xM$ and its orthogonal complement, the subspace $N_xM$. Then, $TN$ is defined in the obvious way: $\{(x,v):x\in M;\ v\in N_xM\}$

Comment: We have that $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The the proof then says to give $V$ a Riemannian metric induced from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $v$ be the normal bundle of $M$ in $V$. Thus $v \subset T_M V$. I don't know much about Riemannian metrics, I don't know why that sentence is included, it doesn't seem to come up later. I understand what you said, but I still don't understand why $v$, which is the normal bundle of $M$ in $V$, is seen as a subset of $T_M V$. I'm on Page 110, Theorem 5.2 of Hirsch's "Differential Topology"

Comment: You may as well take $V$ to be $\mathbb R^n$ itself. Now, since you are working in $\mathbb R^n$, you can just use the dot product. I think of it this way:  $T_xM$ is an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ via the inclusion $d_xi:T_xM\to T_x\mathbb R^n$, so it has an orthogonal complement, which consists of all vectors $v\in T_x\mathbb R^n$ such that $v\perp T_xM$ using the dot product. It is this subspace that we define to be $N_xM$.

Comment: right, and in my post I call that normal bundle $v$. My text says that $v \subset T_M V$, which is different than what you are saying.

Comment: What is $T_MV?$ The point is that at every $v\in \mathbb R^n,\ T_v\mathbb R^n=T_vM\oplus T_v N$ where this direct sum of vector subspaces  is an orthogonal decomposition. Then, $TN$ is constructed in the usual way. So the normal bundle is a subbundle of $T\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I think $T_M V$ is the tangent bundle of $V$ restricted to $M$. $v$ is the normal bundle of $M$ in $V$. So why would the normal bundle of $M$ in $V$ be a subset of the Tangent bundle of $M$ in $V$?  Maybe i'm reading something wrong.

Comment: I read Hirsch's proof. We have $V\subseteq M\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ so it makes sense to define $T_MV$ to be the normal bundle  $\textit{of M}$ in $V$.

Comment: You mean $M \subset V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Okay, looks like I need to review some things then. Thanks!

Comment: Hirsch is a tough read if you're just beginning to study these topics. I suggest Loring Tu's Intro to Manifolds, or Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds. I self-studied them and learned the basics (which is really all I know) from them. Tu's book is undergraduate level, and well-written, while Lee's is somewhat more advanced but the proofs are very clear.

Comment: @Matematleta  Perhaps you should give an official answer to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put together a few things from the comments: If you put a Riemannian metric on $V$ (for example, think of $V\subset\Bbb R^N$ for some $N$ by Whitney), then $\upsilon_p \cong (T_p M)^\perp\subset T_p V$.

What you were reading wrong is that $\upsilon$ is a subbundle of $T_M V$, which is the restriction of $TV$ to $M$. Indeed, $\upsilon \cong (TM)^\perp \subset T_M V$.